# Android: Updating UI from thread in separate class

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, user-interface, handler

I am attempting to update a few UI elements in my app, after a separate class has been updated. The separate class is neither an activity nor a fragment. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Would a handler work well here, if so could you point me toward a acceptable example of handlers?

Comment: Check out [Activity.runOnUiThread](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.app.Activity/runOnUiThread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this in a separe class.

```
public void setView(Activity activity, View view) {
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                /update your view here
            }
        });
    }
```

You can get the view from your activity variable, instead of pass a view, if you prefere.

Comment: Do I really need another thread to just update a few UI elements? Also in order for this to work I'd have to store a reference to my Activity as well as view in the class; Would either of these not be allowed or cause security issues?

Comment: Also my separate class has a reference to the TextView I'd like to update.

Comment: Yes, you need because it is required to run on UiThread to any update on UI. There is no problem of security. The 'problem' i saw is that`s not the best pratice, because you are doing operations in another class that should be done in activity.

Comment: Also where should I be calling Thread.start() for this newly created thread?

Comment: I wouldn't mind updating the ui elements in the main activity, my main concerns were if a race condition occurs and one thread is locked out of accessing a variable while another updated, also the thread needs to continually refresh UI elements and I was unsure as to how to add those UI updates to the UIthread in the main activity.

Comment: You aren't creating a new thread in this example, you're running it on the UI thread.  In the background, runOnUiThread justs posts a Runnable to a Handler running on the UI thread.  There is no new thread created.  Although I would prefer to use a handler directly than to pass the Activity around.

Comment: Lucas Paolillo's solution worked beautifully. Thanks so much to the community for the quick response. It is my first question on SOF. Hopefully I will be a contributor soon!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update any UI elements from a different thread than the main thread. If you are using the main thread, you can pass the View to the method in the other class and make some changes with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the two classes together by perhaps implementing a callback mechanism that will be processed using a handler into your main application thread, assuming that your external class can register a callback with the Activity class.

Or more simply you could use context by allowing a reference to be passed from the Activity to your other class, but you want to make sure you don't leak context.